# Why don't electric charges get attracted to current-carrying wires when they're at rest, when they do feel a force if they're moving?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Why does charge placed at rest near a current-carrying wire experience no force, but if the charge starts moving then it gets attracted toward the current-carrying wire?

Why doesn't charge get attracted to the current carrying wire despite it being at rest?

Comment: *"charge placed at rest near a current-carrying wire experience no force"* It *will* experience some force of electric kind. Only magnetic part of this force will be zero because of the Lorentz force law.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a fact of nature encoded within the system of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_Gaussian_units_convention) which describe electromagnetic interactions classically.

The definition of charge comes from observations, as well as the definition of the magnetic field.

That a charge is attracted to another charge is a law of nature.   That the magnetic dipoles attract and repulse according to their poles is also a law of nature. It can be experimentally shown that a current carrying wire generates a magnetic field, but a charge at rest with the wire does not feel any force. Once the charge is moving it also generates a magnetic field and thus an interaction between a moving charge and the magnetic field occurs.

Going to the underlying particle level , a current is [moving charges](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html) in a conductor:

[image]

Comment: What if you take another inertial frame in which both the stationary charge seems to move? (Give complete calculation for that please)

Answer (score -5):

Electric current can deviate their path in presence of external electric field .